# Renaming image to username while uploading it into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, file-rename

Renaming image  to user name while uploading  in mysql

```
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos_user/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $location="photos_user/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

and my username is

```
$fname= $_POST['fname'];
```

Comment: Read first http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @Ninsuo the image name has to rename as of username

Comment: Can anyone find the solution for this ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];

  $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
  $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
  //$location="photos_user/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos_user/" . $fname.".jpg"); // <--- altered here
?>
```

Comment: You will need to run a check to ensure that the filetype is correct

Comment: no its not working but thanks for the reply

Comment: When you say it is not working - what happens?

Comment: Have you print_r($_FILES) and checked that photos_user exists in the correct directory. Also have you tried hard coding the $fname as say "batman" to ensure that something is being pushed through the $_POST from the form

Comment: thanks chris i have done this in this way $extension = strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], ".");
    rename($image_name,$fname);
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos_user/" .$fname.$extension);

Answer (score 2):

Just replace:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos_user/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

With:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos_user/" . $fname);
```

Comment: no it not working , but thanks for the reply

Comment: how is it not working, do you get an error message? or is simply not working? Ifso you could change the new filepath to an existing absolute path like: /usr/var/www/websitename/images/avatars/username.jpg. Apache does need enough permissions to write the image.

Comment: the name have to change to specified user name and then i should have to save in database. i am not getting any error message just simply not working you line of code